# How to modify a regular expression to restrict characters count minimum 8 to maximum 20

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression. Now I want to modify it to restrict characters count from 8 to 20.

Minimum characters count should be 8 and maximum 20

```
^(\+\d{1,2}\s?)?1?\-?\.?\s?\(?\d{2,6}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3,6}[\s.-]?\d{1,4}$
```

The current expression accepting the following strings but it shouldn't in my case. The string count should be always greater than 8

123456
1234567

Here are more test cases:

https://regex101.com/r/hDNCkT/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookahead to limit the overall length of your match.  After the carat, insert `(?=.{8,20}$)`.  However, if you need to ensure there are 8-20 *digits*, you could use `(?=(\D*\d){8,20}$)` instead.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/hDNCkT/4)